# Combining two separate pieces of code to work together in C#

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StrokeScribeClass ss = new StrokeScribeClass();

        ss.Alphabet = enumAlphabet.DATAMATRIX;
        ss.DataMatrixMinSize = 16;
        ss.ECI = 0;
        ss.UTF8 = false;

        Console.Write("Input : ");
        string txt;
        txt = Console.ReadLine();

        ss.Text = txt;
        int w = ss.BitmapW;
        int h = ss.BitmapH;
        ss.SavePicture(txt + ".bmp", enumFormats.BMP, w * 2, h * 2);
        System.Console.Write(ss.ErrorDescription);
    }
}

class WriteTextFile
{
    static void Second()
    {
        Console.Write("Input : ");
        string txt;
        txt = Console.ReadLine();

  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Chad\Desktop\studio07\rinhoceros\20140428\WriteText.txt", txt);
    }
}
```

First class `Program` is the part where the console makes a datamatrix with the words typed in to the console and second class `WriteTextFile` part ; what I was trying to do is to make a txt file out of the text typed in to the console from first code (class program)
they both work fine separately. I'm thinking having to class might be a problem and static void can be a problem. please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your Second class the data you wish to store in the text file:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StrokeScribeClass ss = new StrokeScribeClass();

        ss.Alphabet = enumAlphabet.DATAMATRIX;
        ss.DataMatrixMinSize = 16;
        ss.ECI = 0;
        ss.UTF8 = false;

        Console.Write("Input : ");
        string txt;
        txt = Console.ReadLine();

        ss.Text = txt;
        int w = ss.BitmapW;
        int h = ss.BitmapH;
        ss.SavePicture(txt + ".bmp", enumFormats.BMP, w * 2, h * 2);
        System.Console.Write(ss.ErrorDescription);

        WriteTextFile.Second(txt);
    }
}


class WriteTextFile
{
    static void Second(string fileText)
    {
        System.IO.File
          .WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Chad\Desktop\studio07\rinhoceros\20140428\WriteText.txt", fileText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried and it says 'WriteTextFile.Second(string)'is inaccessible due to its protection level what does this mean.

Comment: I've figured it out!
it was inaccessible because they were in different two static void in different class. So I changed static void to public static void and it worked!
Thanks guys for helping me out!

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please select it as the correct answer.